# What is the equivalent of R's function "replicate" in Python?

Tags: python, r

I am trying to translate some code to do a Monte Carlo Simulation in Python, specifically the following, but am having a hard time finding the equivalent function replicate into my Jupyter Notebook.

````
estima_probabilidad <- function(clase, num_veces = 10000){
    resultados <- replicate(num_veces, {    # Retorna un vector lógico
        colegas <- sample(dias, clase, replace = TRUE)
        any(duplicated(colegas))
    })

    # Probabilidad:
    mean(resultados) 
}

estima_probabilidad(25)
#> [1] 0.572```
````

Comment: I have removed code tags that are irrelevant to your question (`montecarlo`, `statistics`, `simulation`).

Answer (score 2):

In R, `replicate` is a wrapper around `sapply` which itself is just an (optimised) `for` loop in disguise. So to implement `replicate` in Python you'd use a `for` loop.

Example:

### In R

```r
replicate(5, 0:2, simplify = FALSE)
```

### In Python

```py
[[*range(3)] for _ in range(5)]
#[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]
```

Or more abstractly/generally: `[your_custom_Python_function_returning_a_list for _ in range(5)]` translates to `replicate(5, your_vectorised_custom_R_function, simplify = FALSE)`.

PS. Your R code is not reproducible; `dias` seems to be a global variable defined elsewhere.